# Generating proxy classes using XJC or xmlBeans fails

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, amazon-mws

I am trying to generate proxy classes using XJC 2.2.4-2 and episode files. The initial episode generation worked well using amazon.xsd, however subsequent requests to use the episode are failing.

I have also tried xmlbeans `scomp` command, which also fails.

The command I am running is:

`xjc.exe -extension -b amazon.episode amzn-base.xsd`
and 
`scomp -src amazonGeneratedClasses -out feedsApi.jar new` new is a directory containing all the xsd files.

Which outputs:

[XJC]

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] SCD "AmazonOnly" didnt match any schema component
  line 69 of file:/C:/Users/roberth/Programming_Projects/new/amazon.episode

[ERROR] SCD "Amazon-Vendor-Only" didnt match any schema component
  line 60 of file:/C:/Users/roberth/Programming_Projects/new/amazon.episode

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Line 60:

```
 <jaxb:bindings scd="Amazon-Vendor-Only">
      <jaxb:class ref="amazon.AmazonVendorOnly"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Line 69:

```
  <jaxb:bindings scd="Amazon-Only">
      <jaxb:class ref="amazon.AmazonOnly"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

the files amazon.AmazonVendorOnly and amazon.AmazonOnly do exist.

[XmlBeans]

```
MerchantListingsReport.xsd:27:8: error: Invalid QName value: Can't resolve prefix 'tns'
amzn-header.xsd:17:5: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Header (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:109:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Aspiration (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:118:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: BaseVehicle (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:127:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: BedLength (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:136:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: BedType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:145:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: BodyNumDoors (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:154:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: BodyType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:163:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: BrakeABS (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:172:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: BrakeSystem (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:181:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: CylinderHeadType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:190:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: DisplayOrder (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:191:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: DriveType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:200:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: EngineBase (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:209:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: EngineDesignation (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:218:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: EngineMfr (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:227:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: EngineVIN (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:236:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: EngineVersion (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:252:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: FrontBrakeType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:261:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: FrontSpringType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:270:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: FuelDeliverySubType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:279:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: FuelDeliveryType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:288:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: FuelSystemControlType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:297:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: FuelSystemDesign (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:306:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: FuelType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:323:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: IgnitionSystemType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:332:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Make (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:341:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: MfrBodyCode (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:351:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: MfrLabel (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:360:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Model (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:369:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Note (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:387:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Part (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:396:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: PartType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:405:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Position (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:414:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Qty (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:415:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: RearBrakeType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:424:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: RearSpringType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:433:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Region (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:451:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: SteeringSystem (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:460:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: SteeringType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:469:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: SubModel (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:508:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: TransmissionBase (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:517:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: TransmissionControlType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:526:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: TransmissionMfr (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:535:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: TransmissionMfrCode (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:544:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: TransmissionNumSpeeds (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:553:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: TransmissionType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:562:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: VehicleType (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:571:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: WheelBase (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
AmazonACES.xsd:580:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Years (Original global element found in file: aces.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:4548:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: MaintenanceType (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd
)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:4591:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: ImageStyle (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:4664:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: FileType (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:4706:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: ImageResolution (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd
)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:4756:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: ImageRepresentation (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES
.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:4799:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: ColorMode (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:4846:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: Background (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:4894:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: OrientationView (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd
)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:4977:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: ImageFileEncodeType (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES
.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5065:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: LanguageCode (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5113:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: LinkCode (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5215:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: ItemIDQualifier (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd
)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5270:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: KitsUOM (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5384:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: PackageUOM (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5432:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: PackageDimUOM (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5475:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: ShippingScope (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5518:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: Bulk (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5561:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: WeightUOM (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:5604:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: CountryCode (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6121:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: TransportMethod (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd
)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6168:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: Regulated (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6212:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: PackagingGroupCode (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.
xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6258:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: ExtendedProductInformationCode (Original global type found in file:
 AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6417:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: RegulationsExceptionCode (Original global type found in file: Amazo
nPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6466:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: PriceBreakUOM (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6545:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: PriceUOM (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6681:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: DescriptionCode (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd
)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6748:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: PriceType (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6865:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: OQUOM (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:6974:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: GTINQualifier (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:7025:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: HazardousMaterialCode (Original global type found in file: AmazonPI
ES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:7070:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: StateCode (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:7247:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: ContactType (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.xsd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:7290:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: QualityGradeLevel (Original global type found in file: AmazonPIES.x
sd)
PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd:13:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: PartInformation (Original global element found in file: AmazonPIES
.xsd)
TypeDefinitions.xsd:36:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global type: CurrencyCode (Original global type found in file: PIES_5.0_02_01_2006.xsd
)
Time to build schema type system: 3.525 seconds
BUILD FAILED
```

Unfortunately the XSD files are all marked confidential, so I am unable to share the content of them here. That being said if anyone has any hunches, suggestions or even a direction to look in, please share it.

Comment: From the looks of it, two identical or partly identical schemas get included, so there's duplicate element declarations and/or type definitions. But, it could also be an XML processor bug. I seem to recall running into something similar. Any chance you can provide the schemas?

Comment: The schemas are marked confidential by Amazon, so I can't post them. Most of the files are partially similar to each other and define the same times. I was hoping the episode file would be a work around for this...

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be the answer, since I do not know the exact details of your setup, but the problem strongly reminded me of this so I figure it might help out. Mind that this is only for JAXB using XJC. However, the basis of this issue might actually be a bug in Apache Xerces and/or its JRE equivalent, so it's possible your choice of binding framework won't make a difference. I had the issue with both the JRE Xerces fork and the latest Xerces release, so switching XML API implementations didn't do anything either for me.

I have one Maven project that quite simply contains a main schema, some other schemas that the main one includes (same namespace) and a bindings file. Then I have any number of other Maven projects, each of which have their own schemas that import the main one (different namespaces). Since the JAXB entities for the main schema and its includes are already generated by the first Maven project, I too wished to use an episode file to make sure the other projects would simply extend it, rather than regenerate the code. This would allow me to distribute separate jars.

Here's the Maven pom (Maven 3) for the first, main project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>acme.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>acme-xml-main</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Acme XML main models</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes-${compilerTarget}</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes-${compilerTarget}</testOutputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- Filtering out any svn folders -->
                    <exclude>**/.svn</exclude>
                    <!-- Filtering out JAXB binding files -->
                    <exclude>**/*.xjb</exclude>
                    <!-- Filtering out XML catalogs -->
                    <exclude>**/*.cat</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <!-- First we need to generate Java source files based on the schemas -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb21-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/acme/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaLanguage>XMLSCHEMA</schemaLanguage>
                            <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                            <episode>true</episode>
                            <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                 <source>1.6</source>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The schemas are packaged along with the XJC-generated classes. I want to refer to this project (or more specifically, its jar) in other projects that "extend" it.

Here's the Maven pom for one such extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>acme.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>acme-xml-sub</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Acme XML sub models</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>acme.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>acme-xml-main</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes-${compilerTarget}</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes-${compilerTarget}</testOutputDirectory>
        <!-- Resources to include into the packaged build -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- Filtering out any svn folders -->
                    <exclude>**/.svn</exclude>
                    <!-- Filtering out JAXB binding files -->
                    <exclude>**/*.xjb</exclude>
                    <!-- Filtering out XML catalogs -->
                    <exclude>**/*.cat</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!-- First we need to generate Java source files based on the schemas -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb21-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- The extension flag needs to be on in order to use the episode file -->
                            <args>
                                <arg>-extension</arg>
                            </args>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/acme/sub/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaLanguage>XMLSCHEMA</schemaLanguage>
                            <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                            <!-- No need to generate an episode for this compilation... -->
                            <episode>false</episode>
                            <!-- The catalog makes sure we can resolve the main schema -->
                            <catalog>${basedir}/src/main/resources/acme/sub/schemas/catalog.cat</catalog>
                            <!-- Using the episode file from the main model jar -->
                            <episodes>
                                <episode>
                                    <groupId>acme.xml</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>acme-xml-main</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                                    <scope>compile</scope>
                                </episode>
                            </episodes>
                            <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <excludes>
                        <!-- This exclude avoids compiling the ObjectFactory class that -->
                        <!-- XJC insists on generating for the default package name of the main -->
                        <!-- namespace. Please leave this in to avoid any trouble. -->
                        <exclude>**/acme/main/ObjectFactory.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                 <source>1.6</source>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The first problem I ran into was that the main schema could not be found for importing into the sub schemas. Let's call the main schema `main.xsd`, assume it has target namespace `http://www.acme.com` and that its JAXB classes are placed in package `acme.main` courtesy of the bindings file.

For resolving schemas, you can use a catalog. So this was the first thing I tried. In the sub project, I added a catalog.cat file with these contents:

```
--
  Resolving the main XML Schema system ID.
--
SYSTEM "main.xsd" "classpath:/acme/schemas/main.xsd"

--
  Resolving the main namespace to the corresponding schema file.
--
PUBLIC "http://www.acme.com" "classpath:/acme/schemas/main.xsd"
```

You can see the catalog.cat referenced in the second Maven pom above.
I tried a whole bunch of different approaches for the SYSTEM ID, but regardless of what I did, resolving a schema on the classpath just didn't seem to work. So I turned to creating a custom catalog resolver that would handle this for me. This is a Java class I packaged with the main schema/JAXB models jar file. I added this dependency to the first Maven pom...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
    <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
    <version>20050927</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

... and created a custom catalog resolver that would always link certain system IDs and the main namespace URI to my main schema.

Then I adjusted the XJC generation config of the second Maven pom to this:

```
<!-- First we need to generate Java source files based on the schemas -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb21-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2</version>
    <!-- Need this dependency for the custom catalog resolver -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>acme.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>acme-xml-main</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc-generate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- The extension flag needs to be on in order to use the episode file -->
                <args>
                    <arg>-extension</arg>
                </args>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/acme/sub/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaLanguage>XMLSCHEMA</schemaLanguage>
                <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                <!-- No need to generate an episode for this compilation... -->
                <episode>false</episode>
                <!-- The catalog makes sure we can resolve the main schema -->
                <catalog>${basedir}/src/main/resources/acme/sub/schemas/catalog.cat</catalog>
                <catalogResolver>acme.xml.tools.AcmeCatalogResolver</catalogResolver>
                <!-- Using the episode file from the general model bundle -->
                <episodes>
                    <episode>
                        <groupId>acme.xml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>acme-xml-main</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </episode>
                </episodes>
                <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

With this, and some console output from the catalog resolver to find out what was going on, the main schema could finally be resolved from the classpath. But things weren't quite ready yet.

Whenever I used includes in the main schema, to make sure it could be broken up across different files and group definitions for clarity, I would find that the XML processor complained of duplicate definitions. It would seem that the various files would be resolved via different paths (some system ID, others namespace, some full path, others relative...) and this seemed to cause issues. Although these various paths pointed to what was essentially the same file, anything loaded from it would be regarded as separate definitions by the XML processor. It seems the XML validation API just isn't good at creating one coherent Schema object and just keeps looking stuff up, not realizing it's looking at the same file through different paths.

So I added yet more stuff to my custom catalog resolver to make sure included files would always be approached in the same manner. Here is the resulting class:

```
package acme.xml.tools;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class AcmeCatalogResolver extends CatalogResolver {

    private final static String namespace = "http://www.acme.com";
    private final static Set<String> systemIDs;
    static {
        final Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>();
        temp.add("main.xsd");
        temp.add("Main.xsd");
        temp.add("MAIN.xsd");
        systemIDs = Collections.unmodifiableSet(temp);
    }

    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {

        //If the public ID is the main namespace, get the input source
        //based on the system ID
        if(publicId != null && publicId.trim().equals(namespace)) {
            final InputSource source = getInputSource(systemId);
            source.setPublicId(publicId);
            return source;
        }

        //Otherwise, check if the system ID is one of the allowed references
        //to the main schema and return that
        if(systemId != null && systemIDs.contains(systemId.trim())) {
            final InputSource source = getMainSchemaInputSource();
            source.setPublicId(publicId);
            return source;
        }

        //Still nothing: check for file or jar URIs to the main schema
        if(systemId != null && (systemId.startsWith("file:") || 
                systemId.startsWith("jar:"))) {
            boolean match = false;
            for(final String id : systemIDs) {
                match = systemId.endsWith(id);
                if(match)
                    break;
            }
            if(match) {
                final InputSource source = getMainSchemaInputSource();
                source.setPublicId(publicId);
                return source;
            }
        }

        //Final option: use only the system ID to find the source
        if(systemId != null && !systemId.isEmpty()) {
            final InputSource source = getInputSource(systemId);
            source.setPublicId(publicId);
            return source;
        }

        //This should not be necessary, but just in case...
        return super.resolveEntity(publicId, systemId);

    }

    @Override
    public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {

        if(href != null && href.trim().equals(namespace)) {
            final StreamSource source = getMainSchemaSource();
            source.setPublicId(href);
            return getMainSchemaSource();
        }

        return super.resolve(href, base);

    }

    @Override
    public String getResolvedEntity(String string, String string1) {

        return super.getResolvedEntity(string, string1);

    }

    private InputSource getInputSource(String systemId) {

        final int lastSlash = systemId.lastIndexOf('/');
        if(lastSlash >= 0)
            systemId = systemId.substring(lastSlash + 1);
        final int lastBackSlash = systemId.lastIndexOf('\\');
        if(lastBackSlash >= 0)
            systemId = systemId.substring(lastBackSlash + 1);

        final URL url = 
            this.getClass().getResource("/acme/schemas/" + systemId);

        final InputStream stream = 
            this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/acme/schemas/" + systemId);

        final InputSource source = new InputSource(stream);
        source.setSystemId(url.toString());

        return source;

    }

    private InputSource getMainSchemaInputSource() {

        final URL url = 
            this.getClass().getResource("/acme/schemas/main.xsd");

        final InputStream stream = 
            this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/acme/schemas/main.xsd");

        final InputSource source = new InputSource(stream);
        source.setSystemId(url.toString());

        return source;

    }

    private StreamSource getGeneralSchemaSource() {

        final URL url = 
            this.getClass().getResource("/acme/schemas/main.xsd");

        final InputStream stream = 
            this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/acme/schemas/main.xsd");

        final StreamSource source = new StreamSource(stream);
        source.setSystemId(url.toString());

        return source;

    }

}
```

With that, I finally got it working. I hope that this might in some way enlighten the path to a solution for you.

Yeah, it's dirty as hell. I'm extending a Sun internals class. I'm basically just using the catalog file to direct requests for the main schema or its namespace to some hacky class that hardcodes the whole deal. But at least it works this way.
Since apparently Sun couldn't be friggin' arsed to resolve issues in its JAXP implementation that have been OPEN FOR YEARS! And I don't think Oracle gives a flying crap either. But you better be damn sure they'll try to force XML down your throat for any program interaction that dares as much as step off the motherboard. And Apache's Xerces implementation hasn't resolved any of this either. Not that I can really blame them given the disaster that is the W3C XML Schema spec.

Sorry about that last bit, I just need to vent every now and then when it turns out that doing anything outside of the trivial stuff with XML Schema in Java turns immediately into mental torture. If JAXB wasn't so darn useful I wouldn't bother with this.

Comment: Jeez eh. I appreciate the effort in this post, I'm going to need to research and see if this resolves the issue currently I don't use maven so I have some learning to do. Thanks again

Comment: Well, it's just a build tool. But it makes the XJC setup a bit more transparent for me. I'm not at all certain the issue you face is the same, but should you come across the same challenges as me, this could save you some time. I had a lot of studying and digging to do for this as well before reaching a working setup.